# html2canvas error: Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1

Tags: jquery, canvas, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to convert a div on a canvas. Like this:

```html
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/html2canvas/html2canvas.js"></script>
...
<body id="body">
  <div id="demo">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
<script>
$('#demo').html2canvas({
onrendered: function( canvas ) {
  var img = canvas.toDataURL()
  window.open(img);
}
});
</script>
```

and I get this error: **"Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1"** in html2canvas.js:

```js
ctx.drawImage( canvas, bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.width, bounds.height, 0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height );
```

Does anyone have idea about's what happening?

Comment: I don't know if you have experienced the same with this error but what i found was strange with me was it worked in chrome but then tested on IE and hit this error. Maybe chrome is more lenient.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever you call `drawImage` on a canvas and you want to crop an image, you have to pass in 9 values.

```
ctx.drawImage(
imageObject,
sourceX,
sourceY,
sourceWidth,
sourceHeight,
destX,
destY,
destWidth,
destHeight);
```

now that's a lot of stuff! It's really easy to make errors: to avoid them, let me explain how drawImage works when cropping an image.

Imagine to draw a square on a piece of paper. The top-left corner of the square you're drawing is positioned at `sourceX` pixels and `sourceY` pixels where 0 is the top-left corner of your piece of paper. The dimension in pixels of the square you're drawing are defined by `sourceWidth` and `sourceHeight`.

Everything inside of the square you've defined, will now be cut and pasted inside of your canvas at the position (in pixels) `destX` and `destY` (where 0 is the top-left corner of your canvas).

Because we're not in real life, the square you cut may be stretched and have a different dimension. This is why you also have to define `destWidth` and `destHeight`

Here's a graphical representation of all this.

[image: none]

To get back to your question, `Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1` usually appears when the square you're trying to cut is bigger than the actual piece of paper, or you're trying to cut the piece of paper in a position where it doesn't exists (like `sourceX = -1`, which is impossible for obvious reasons).

I have no idea what `bounds.left`, `bounds.top` and the others are, but I'm 99.9% sure that they're wrong values. Try to `console.log` them and compare them with the image object you're providing (in this case, the canvas).

```
console.log(canvas.width);
console.log(canvas.height);
console.log(bounds.left);
console.log(bounds.top);
ecc....
```

Comment: looking at this link, it seems that the parameter order has been shuffled
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Example SourceX is now the 6th parameter

Comment: Thanks for your input mishal153. Are you sure of that? Because I'm watching the link you provided and "sx" (sourceX) is still the second parameter, not the 6th. Furthermore, it would be extremely counterproductive to shuffle the order of arguments, for reasons of backward compatibility: I highly doubt anyone would have done that.

Answer (score 9):

[This](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/183) is the `html2canvas` bug report.

I was able to fix the **Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1** by patching the html2canvas.js file.

replace this:

```
ctx.drawImage(canvas, bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.width, bounds.height, 0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

by this:

```
var imgData = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.width, bounds.height);
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

i would say that you probably have some `float` attribute or `fixed` position on a div that cause a container to be of height 0 while the content has a superior height.
i had this problem before caused by it because *html2canvas* can't handle a content larger than it's container.
for example, if you have something like this:

```
<div>
  <img url="..." style="float: right;">
</div>
```

*html2canvas* will raise this error because `div` has a height of 0 while the `img` is bigger.
possible correction will be to force height of div to be supperior to image height.

thanks Saturnix for your detailed answer, you helped me find out where it came from.

i hope this could help you,

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Problem is happened when I tried to use canvas inside a hidden element. In my case I am using Bootstrap modal and the canvas inside it.

Solution is: **"Implement canvas codes after element is fully visible"**.

In my case I have to use `$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){})` instead of `$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){})`, because modal element is fully appeared on `shown.bs.modal` event ; )