# Any particular reason I'm getting "Component not available" and "Index Size Error:Dom exception" errors on this code

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I'm Javascript/HTML5 newbie and I'm building what is supposed to be a simple blackjack game.  I'm learning from a book and I presume my code is fine (checked it a lot) and I know my image files are correctly named. I've included this all in one html file for simplicity. 
Any particular reason why this wouldn't be loading into the canvas. Both Chrome and Firefox appear to be taking particular issue with the deal and newGame function. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. (also ignore ugly indenting still new to the stackoverflow tools.)

Thanks

```js
var cwidth = 800;
    var cheight = 600;
    var cardw = 75;
    var cardh = 107;
    var playerxp = 100;
    var playeryp = 300;
    var housexp = 500;
    var houseyp = 100;
    var housetotal;
    var playertotal;
    var pi = 0;
    var hi = 0;
    var deck = [];
    var playerhand = [];
    var househand = [];
    var back = new Image();
    
    function init () {
        ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
     ctx.font = "italic 20pt Georgia";
     ctx.fillstyle = 'blue';
     builddeck();
     back.src = 'cardback.png';
      canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas');
      window.addEventListener('keydown', getkey, false);
     shuffle();
     dealstart(); 
    }
    
    function getkey(event) {
     var keyCode;
     if (event == null)
     {
      keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
    
      window.event.preventDefault();
     }
     else {
      keyCode = event.keyCode;
      event.preventDefault();
     }
        
        switch(keyCode) {
    
         case 68:
         deal();
         break;
    
         case 72:
         playerdone();
         break;
    
         case 78:
         newgame();
         break;
    
         default:
         alert("press d, h or n please.");
    
    
        } 
    }
    
    function dealstart() {
     playerhand[pi] = dealfromdeck(1);
    
     ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);
     playerxp = playerxp+30;
     pi++;
    
     househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
     ctx.drawImage(back, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
     housexp = housexp+20;
     hi++;
    
     playerhand[pi] = dealfromdeck(1);
     ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);
     playerxp = playerxp+30;
     pi++;
    
     househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
     ctx.drawImage(househand[hi].picture, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
     housexp = housexp+20;
     hi++;
    }
    
    function deal() {
    
     playerhand[pi] = dealfromdeck(1);
     ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);
     playerxp = playerxp+30;
     pi++;
    
     if (more_to_house()) {
      househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
      ctx.drawImage(househand[hi].picture, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
      housexp = housexp+20;
      hi++;
     }
    }
    
    function more_to_house() {
     var ac = 0;
     var i;
     var sumup = 0;
    
     for(i = 0; i < hi; i++) {
      sumup += househand[i].value;
    
      if (househand[i].value==1){ac++;}
     }
    
      if (ac>0) {
       if ((sumup+10)<=21){
    
        sumup+=10;
       }
      } 
    
      housetotal = sumup;
    
      if (sumup<17){
       return true;
      }
    
      else{
       return false;
      }
    
    }
    
    function dealfromdeck(who){
     var card;
     var ch = 0;
    
     while ((deck[ch].dealt>0)&&(ch<51)){
      ch++;
     }
    
     if (ch>=51) {
      ctx.fillText("NO MORE CARDS IN DECK. Reload.", 200, 250);
      ch = 51;
     }
    
     deck[ch].dealt = who;
    
     card = deck[ch];
     return card;
    }
    
    function builddeck() {
     var n;
     var si;
     var suitname = ["clubs", "hearts", "spades", "diamonds"];
     var i;
     i=0;
     var picname;
     var nums = ["a", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "j", "q", "k"];
    
     for (si=0; si<4; si++) {
      for(n=0; n<13; n++) {
       picname = suitname[si]+"-"+nums[n]+"-75.png";
       deck[i] = new MCard(n+1, suitname[si], picname);
       i++;
      }
     }
    }
    
    function MCard(n, s, picname){
    
     this.num = n;
     if (n>10) n = 10;
     this.value = n;
     this.suit = s;
     this.picture = new Image();
     this.picture.src = picname;
     this.dealt = 0;
    }
    
    function add_up_player (){
     var ac = 0;
     var i;
     var sumup = 0;
      for(i=0; i<pi; i++){
       sumup += playerhand[i].value;
    
       if (playerhand[i].value==1)
       {
        ac++;
       }
      }
    
      if (ac>0) {
       if((sumup+10)<=21){
        sumup+=10;
       }
      }
    
      return sumup;
    }
    
    function playerdone() {
     while (more_to_house()) {
      househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
      ctx.drawImage(back, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
      housexp = housexp+20;
      hi++;
     }
     showhouse();
      playertotal = add_up_player();
      if (playertotal > 21) {
    
       if (housetotal > 21) {
        ctx.fillText("You and the house both went bust.", 30, 100);
       }
       else{
        ctx.fillText("You went over and lost.", 30 , 100);
       }
    
      }
        else
        if (housetotal > 21) {
         ctx.fillText("You Won.  The house went bust.", 30, 100);
        }
    
       else
         if (playertotal >= housetotal) {
          if (playertotal > housetotal) {
           ctx.fillText("You won.", 30, 100);
          }
          else {
           ctx.fillText("You draw.", 30 , 100);
          }
    
         } 
    
         else
          if(housetotal <= 21) {
           ctx.fillText("You Lost.", 30, 100);
          }
         else {
          ctx.fillText("You won because the house went over.");
         }
       }
    
    function newgame() {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
     pi = 0;
     hi = 0;
     playerxp = 100;
     housexp = 500;
     dealstart();
    }
    
    function showhouse() {
     var i;
     housexp = 500;
     for (i=0; i<hi; i++){
      ctx.drawImage(househand[i].picture, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
      housexp = housexp+20;
     }
    }
    
    function shuffle() {
     var i = deck.length - 1;
     var s;
     while (i>0) {
      s = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
      swapindeck(s,i);
      i--;
     }
    }
    
    function swapindeck(j, k) {
     var hold = new MCard(deck[j].num, deck[j].suit, deck[j].picture.src);
     deck[j] = deck[k];
     deck[k] = hold;
    }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: oblique;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
       <head>
       <title>BlackJack</title>
    
    </head>
    
    <body onLoad = "init();">
    <header>Press d for deal or 1 more card, h for hold, n for new game.</header>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height = "500">
    Your Browser doesn't support the Html5 element canvas.
    </canvas>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you explain what's exactely the problem ? I mean what do you have like errors. Use Firedebug of Firefox or chrome's console to see what are the messages you got.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Chrome is giving this error "Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1" on this line  "ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);" in each of the functions using it. It's to draw the card on the canvas.

Comment: Take a look at the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328764/html2canvas-error-uncaught-error-indexsizeerror-dom-exception-1

Comment: Sweet meat! Thanks for your time, I'll let you know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I actually get this error, for the same line you specified:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.

Which means the image you are trying to draw cannot be found in a directory to be drawn.

So I replaced the static code images you had with external links and the code works fine:

```js
var cwidth = 800;
    var cheight = 600;
    var cardw = 75;
    var cardh = 107;
    var playerxp = 100;
    var playeryp = 300;
    var housexp = 500;
    var houseyp = 100;
    var housetotal;
    var playertotal;
    var pi = 0;
    var hi = 0;
    var deck = [];
    var playerhand = [];
    var househand = [];
    var back = new Image();

    function init() {
        ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        ctx.font = "italic 20pt Georgia";
        ctx.fillstyle = 'blue';
        builddeck();
        back.src = 'http://www.jimknapp.com/Cards/Non-Bicycle_files/image001.jpg';
        canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas');
        window.addEventListener('keydown', getkey, false);
        shuffle();
        dealstart();
    }

    function getkey(event) {
        var keyCode;
        if (event == null) {
            keyCode = window.event.keyCode;

            window.event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            keyCode = event.keyCode;
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        switch (keyCode) {

            case 68:
                deal();
                break;

            case 72:
                playerdone();
                break;

            case 78:
                newgame();
                break;

            default:
                alert("press d, h or n please.");


        }
    }

    function dealstart() {
        playerhand[pi] = dealfromdeck(1);

        ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);
        playerxp = playerxp + 30;
        pi++;

        househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
        ctx.drawImage(back, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
        housexp = housexp + 20;
        hi++;

        playerhand[pi] = dealfromdeck(1);
        ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);
        playerxp = playerxp + 30;
        pi++;

        househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
        ctx.drawImage(househand[hi].picture, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
        housexp = housexp + 20;
        hi++;
    }

    function deal() {

        playerhand[pi] = dealfromdeck(1);
        ctx.drawImage(playerhand[pi].picture, playerxp, playeryp, cardw, cardh);
        playerxp = playerxp + 30;
        pi++;

        if (more_to_house()) {
            househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
            ctx.drawImage(househand[hi].picture, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
            housexp = housexp + 20;
            hi++;
        }
    }

    function more_to_house() {
        var ac = 0;
        var i;
        var sumup = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < hi; i++) {
            sumup += househand[i].value;

            if (househand[i].value == 1) { ac++; }
        }

        if (ac > 0) {
            if ((sumup + 10) <= 21) {

                sumup += 10;
            }
        }

        housetotal = sumup;

        if (sumup < 17) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function dealfromdeck(who) {
        var card;
        var ch = 0;

        while ((deck[ch].dealt > 0) && (ch < 51)) {
            ch++;
        }

        if (ch >= 51) {
            ctx.fillText("NO MORE CARDS IN DECK. Reload.", 200, 250);
            ch = 51;
        }

        deck[ch].dealt = who;

        card = deck[ch];
        return card;
    }

    function builddeck() {
        var n;
        var si;
        var suitname = ["C", "H", "S", "D"];
        var i;
        i = 0;
        var picname;
        var nums = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "J", "Q", "K"];

        for (si = 0; si < 4; si++) {
            for (n = 0; n < 13; n++) {
                picname =  "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/" + nums[n] + suitname[si] + ".png";
                deck[i] = new MCard(n + 1, suitname[si], picname);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    function MCard(n, s, picname) {

        this.num = n;
        if (n > 10) n = 10;
        this.value = n;
        this.suit = s;
        this.picture = new Image();
        this.picture.src = picname;
        this.dealt = 0;
    }

    function add_up_player() {
        var ac = 0;
        var i;
        var sumup = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < pi; i++) {
            sumup += playerhand[i].value;

            if (playerhand[i].value == 1) {
                ac++;
            }
        }

        if (ac > 0) {
            if ((sumup + 10) <= 21) {
                sumup += 10;
            }
        }

        return sumup;
    }

    function playerdone() {
        while (more_to_house()) {
            househand[hi] = dealfromdeck(2);
            ctx.drawImage(back, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
            housexp = housexp + 20;
            hi++;
        }
        showhouse();
        playertotal = add_up_player();
        if (playertotal > 21) {

            if (housetotal > 21) {
                ctx.fillText("You and the house both went bust.", 30, 100);
            } else {
                ctx.fillText("You went over and lost.", 30, 100);
            }

        } else
        if (housetotal > 21) {
            ctx.fillText("You Won.  The house went bust.", 30, 100);
        } else
        if (playertotal >= housetotal) {
            if (playertotal > housetotal) {
                ctx.fillText("You won.", 30, 100);
            } else {
                ctx.fillText("You draw.", 30, 100);
            }

        } else
        if (housetotal <= 21) {
            ctx.fillText("You Lost.", 30, 100);
        } else {
            ctx.fillText("You won because the house went over.");
        }
    }

    function newgame() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);
        pi = 0;
        hi = 0;
        playerxp = 100;
        housexp = 500;
        dealstart();
    }

    function showhouse() {
        var i;
        housexp = 500;
        for (i = 0; i < hi; i++) {
            ctx.drawImage(househand[i].picture, housexp, houseyp, cardw, cardh);
            housexp = housexp + 20;
        }
    }

    function shuffle() {
        var i = deck.length - 1;
        var s;
        while (i > 0) {
            s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            swapindeck(s, i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    function swapindeck(j, k) {
        var hold = new MCard(deck[j].num, deck[j].suit, deck[j].picture.src);
        deck[j] = deck[k];
        deck[k] = hold;
    }
```

```css
body {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }

    footer {
        display: block;
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        font-style: oblique;
    }

    header {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>BlackJack</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="init();">
    <header>Press d for deal or 1 more card, h for hold, n for new game.</header>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500">
        Your Browser doesn't support the Html5 element canvas.
    </canvas>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

If you do get this error, I've specified, while using external links, then it's probably because you have an ad blocker blocking the image from being loaded in externally